# I want to choose NAME and FILM from two ComboBox and put the selected items in H2 DB

Tags: java

I fill out two ComboBox from h2 db.In combobox you can see only name.
Haw can i get the ID for the selected item from my combo box. and through id to write new executeQuery

```
JComboBox<String> comboBox = new JComboBox<>();
    try {
        String sql="SELECT clientid,name,lastname FROM client";
        conn = DBConnector.getConnection();
        state = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        result = state.executeQuery();
        while(result.next()) {
            String name = result.getString("name");
            String lname = result.getString("lastname");
            comboBox.addItem(name+" "+lname);

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    comboBox.setBounds(10, 91, 146, 22);
    contentPane.add(comboBox);
JComboBox<String> comboBox_1 = new JComboBox<>();

    try {
        String sql="SELECT title,yearpub FROM films";
        conn = DBConnector.getConnection();
        state = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        result = state.executeQuery();
        while(result.next()) {
            String name = result.getString("title");
            String year = result.getString("yearpub");
            comboBox_1.addItem(name+" "+year);

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    comboBox_1.setBounds(194, 91, 146, 22);
    contentPane.add(comboBox_1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding only the first name and last name to the first `JComboBox` in this line of the code you posted:

```
comboBox.addItem(name+" "+lname);
```

The ID is **not** stored in the `JComboBox` model and therefore not in the selected item.

By default, `JComboBox` displays the `String` returned by method `toString()` of the objects in its model, so an easy solution is to create a custom class and a custom `toString()` method. For example for the first `JComboBox`:

```
public class Client {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String lname;

    public Client(int id, String name, String lname) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.lname = lname;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name + " " + lname;
    }
}
```

Then you create and populate a `JComboBox` like so:

```
JComboBox<Client> comboBox = new JComboBox<>();
try {
    String sql="SELECT clientid,name,lastname FROM client";
    conn = DBConnector.getConnection();
    state = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    result = state.executeQuery();
    while(result.next()) {
        int id = result.getInt("clientid");
        String name = result.getString("name");
        String lname = result.getString("lastname");
        comboBox.addItem(new Client(id, name, lname));
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Now when you call method `getSelectedItem()` in `JComboBox`, it will return a `Client` object which contains the ID.

```
Object obj = comboBox.getSelectedItem();
Client client = (Client) obj;
int id = client.getId();
```

Note that the `toString()` method of class `Client` means that `JComboBox` will display only `name` and `lname`.

Answer (score 0):

You use strings for the combobox, however you are really should use items, incl. ID and all the stuff. To present the item in a combobox [you should use custom renderer](https://www.codejava.net/java-se/swing/create-custom-gui-for-jcombobox)
When implementing the function

```
public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value,
            int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus)
```

pay attention that `value` will be your custom item